# Error al usar configuración con base de datos mongodb utilizando hibernate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate

Quisiera saber acerca del error que muestra mi aplicación al tratar de usar un archivo de configuración alterno para otra base de datos en mi caso mongo, al abrir una session recibo el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 
>     Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Y más abajo, en el log del error marca

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
>   Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Esta es mi archivo hibernateUtil.java

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {


        Configuration cfgogm = new Configuration().configure("mongo-hibernate.cfg.xml");
        // ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry)new
        // StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfgogm.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = cfgogm.buildSessionFactory();
        sessionFactory.getStatistics().setStatisticsEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        System.out.println("SessionFactory is not Null");
    }
    System.out.println(sessionFactory);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Mi metodo main del cual creo un objeto y ejecuto la prueba que arroja el error mencionado.

```
    Session session = new mongoHibernateUtil().getSessionFactory().openSession();

    if (!sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("SessionFactory is Still Open!! Now Attempting to close the SessionFactory");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        session.beginTransaction();     
        session.save(new Publication(1,"09/02/2016",1,"1"));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Insert Successful");
        session.close();
    }

    System.exit(0);


Mi archivo de configuracion de hibernate para la conexion a mongodb.

<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">infinispan</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.username">mongo</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">./Indexes</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy">single</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
```

Comment: mas abajo en el log del error marca causado por,
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: Hola @TavoRuiz. ¡Bienvenido a [so.es]! Edité la pregunta con lo que comentaste. Y quizás sería más útil que publiques el código que dispara el error. Encontrarás el enlace **[edit]** para agregar más información en la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano Gracias, soy nuevo en esta pagina.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta esta bien planteada. Y la excepción dice que el acceso a DialectResolutionInfo no puede ser null cuando 'hibernate.dialect' no esta establecido. Por lo tanto a mi me parece que se resuelve agregando esta linea en tu sessionFactory para establecer hibernate.dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect"/>
```

Otra forma podría ser así:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @abrahamhs  probe la configuracion del archivo mongo-hibernate.cfg.xml con la linea que me respondiste y me retorno el sgte error.


Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]


Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Comment: creo que tienes que definir una estrategia de identificador para ids de los registros de las tablas, por eso, el error, perdon por no ponerlo ahorita pero ya me voy, tal vez mañana, si tengo tiempo

Comment: vale, gracias. @abrahamhs

Comment: El problema orginal que planteas en tu pregunta ya quedo corregido. Para el nuevo problema, en tu clase donde mapeas la tabla, en el hbm.xml ´<id column="Id" name="id" type="integer">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>´  . Mira esto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-hibernate y esto otro http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id